# Html 5 video tag not working in safari 5.1.7 and IE 9.0

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am working in cake 3 and I want to use video in my project. but it not working in safari 5.1.7 and IE 9.0.

I used this code:

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls="true" >
     <source src="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/video/rr.webm');?>" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both IE 9.0 and Safari 5.1.7  should support `<video>` tag ( See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) ).

However, the format `webm`, Multimedia format designed to provide a royalty-free, high-quality open video compression format for use with HTML5 video, [is not supported in IE and Safari](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webm) (all versions at this moment). You should provide an alternative source.